# Pysnmp: How to change PDU on fly and send an SNMP request to multiple devices on the same time?

Tags: pysnmp

On this post http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/current/v1arch/manager/cmdgen/getnext-v1.html I was able to change the pdu on the fly for one device at a time, but I struggled to send a request to more the one device at the same time.
I tried doing the following:

```
transportDispatcher.registerTransport(
  udp.domainName, udp.UdpSocketTransport().openClientMode()
)
transportDispatcher.sendMessage(
  encoder.encode(reqMsg), udp.domainName, ('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)
)
transportDispatcher.jobStarted(1)
transportDispatcher.registerTransport(
  udp.domainName, udp.UdpSocketTransport().openClientMode()
)
transportDispatcher.sendMessage(
  encoder.encode(reqMsg), udp.domainName, ('192.168.0.49', 161)
)
transportDispatcher.jobStarted(1)
```

But I get the following error: "pysnmp.carrier.error.CarrierError: Transport (1, 3, 6, 1, 6, 1, 1) already registered".
So how do I change PDU on the fly and send a SNMP request to multiple devices on the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, you are not changing PDU on the fly, rather you are building different SNMP messages and sending them independently through the same network transport.

The problem with your code is that you are trying to register multiple UDP sockets under the same SNMP transport ID. You do not need that, as you could send UDP datagrams to multiple destinations through a single socket.

Therefore transport registration should only be performed once in your code:

```
# one-time initialization
transportDispatcher.registerTransport(
  udp.domainName, udp.UdpSocketTransport().openClientMode()
)

# messaging
while True:
    transportDispatcher.sendMessage(
        encoder.encode(reqMsg), udp.domainName, ('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)
    )
    transportDispatcher.jobStarted(1)
    ...
```

Side note: DNS resolver is not asynchronous, make sure it works fast enough or use IP addresses for addressing your agents.

If you want multiple UDP sockets for some reason, use different SNMP transport IDs for them for both registration and use:

```
transportDispatcher.registerTransport(
    udp.domainName + (1,), udp.UdpSocketTransport().openClientMode()
)
transportDispatcher.registerTransport(
    udp.domainName + (2,), udp.UdpSocketTransport().openClientMode()
)
```

Comment: So what would be faster? changing pdu on the fly or 'building different SNMP messages and sending them independently through the same network transport'? What is the  difference between the both? And could you please show me how I could change the PDU on the fly in pysnmp, because I went over http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/contents.html#packet-level-snmp and didn't find anything. I would also like to arrange a chat on skype with you for some price, so you could answer some of my questions. If your interested reply on gmail.